# How to synchronize two branches in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, synchronization, branch

In my local fork of the upstream Mercurial repository I have multiple branches. Prior to beginning work on one of the outdated branches `feature` I would like to obtain all the changes from the local `default` branch. How do I do that? When I execute:

```
hg up feature
hg merge default
```

I obtain an error message:

```
abort: merging with a working directory ancestor has no effect
```

Comment: Show `hg branches`

Comment: And maybe DAG (part of) - it seems, what head of default is far-parent of `feature` (no diverged history after branching?)

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to obtain all the changes from the local default branch.

I would do a `hg pull` first.
Then `hg up feature`, to switch to such branch in case you are on another branch.

Then bring `default` changes into `feature` by doing `hg merge default`

> abort: merging with a working directory ancestor has no effect

Such message indicates that the parent of the current revision at `feature` is the latest revision (or tip) in `default` in your working copy.